# Partial derivatives using Einstein / Index notation

Tags: partial-derivative, matrix-calculus, tensors, index-notation

I've been trying to compute a partial derivative of an arbitrary function for a while using index notation but I think I am missing something.

Let $\zeta$ be some well behaved scalar function which we apply element-wise to some vector $W^{i}_{k} x^{k}$. I wish to compute the following derivative.

$$\begin{aligned} 
\frac{\partial \zeta(W^{i}_{k} x^{k}) }{\partial x^{j}} 
&= \frac{\partial \zeta(W^{i}_{k} x^{k}) }{\partial (W^{r}_{p} x^{p})} \frac{\partial (W^{r}_{q} x^{q}) }{\partial x^{j}} \\
&= \frac{\partial \zeta(W^{i}_{k} x^{k}) }{\partial (W^{r}_{p} x^{p})} W^{r}_{q} \delta^{q}_{j} \\
&= \frac{\partial \zeta(W^{i}_{k} x^{k}) }{\partial (W^{r}_{p} x^{p})} W^{r}_{j}
\end{aligned}$$

Where $W^{i}_{k}$ is a constant matrix with respect to $x^{j}$. The problem comes when I try to simplify the remaning derivative which I think I should be able to express as following,

$$\begin{aligned} 
\frac{\partial \zeta(W^{i}_{k} x^{k}) }{\partial x^{j}} 
&= \frac{\partial \zeta(W^{i}_{k} x^{k}) }{\partial (W^{r}_{p} x^{p})} W^{r}_{j} \\
&= \zeta^{\prime}(W^{i}_{k} x^{k}) \color{red}{\Delta} W^{r}_{j}
\end{aligned}$$

Where $\color{red}{\Delta}$ should be a term that transform $\zeta^{\prime}$ to a diagonal matrix and allows me to multiply this $diag(\zeta^{\prime})$ with $W$. Thus, with this insight I can fill what is "missing",

$$\begin{aligned} 
\frac{\partial \zeta(W^{i}_{k} x^{k}) }{\partial x^{j}} 
&= \zeta^{\prime}(W^{l}_{k} x^{k}) \Delta^{i}_{lr} W^{r}_{j}
\end{aligned}$$

$$\begin{aligned} 
\Delta^{i}_{lr} =
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if} \quad i = l = r \\
0 & otherwise
\end{cases}
\end{aligned}$$

But this seems quite artificial to me since I am adding the "missing element". So I was wondering if I commited a mistake somewhere along the way.

Comment: Try the coordinate change $u^i=W^i_kx^k$ and examine $\frac{\partial \bar{f}(u(x))}{\partial x^j}$. The gradient transforms like a covariant vector so you can reuse the transformation coefficients $W^i_j$ should you happen to find one on the other side :)

Comment: It is not clear for me what you are trying to simplify, because $\frac{\partial \zeta(W^{i}_{k} x^{k}) }{\partial (W^{r}_{p} x^{p})}$ is better to write as $\frac{\partial \zeta(y) }{\partial y}|_{y=W^{r}_{p} x^{p}}$ or $\zeta'(W^{r}_{p} x^{p})$. Simple already.

Comment: I suspect the assignment is to show that $\frac{\partial f(u) }{\partial u^l}\frac{\partial u^l}{\partial x^k}=\frac{\partial \bar{f}}{\partial x^k}$ or in other words $W^T\nabla f(\mathbf{u})=\nabla\bar{f}(\mathbf{x})$. But who knows...

Comment: I was just trying to rewrite the first partial as a matrix, or more precisely as a (1,1)-tensor $R^{i}_{j}$, because the derivative of a vector with respect to another vector is a matrix. The $\zeta^{\prime}(W^{l}_{k} x^{k})$  only has one free index so if lost the other one along the way. I'll try the coordinate change.